# Splitting VSCode screen

Tags: visual-studio-code, layout

I'm looking for how to split a visual studio screen such that on the left we have the code and on the right the output and the bottom the console. Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to click on this icon [image: split icon]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Doing that only splits the editor for me. I'm not the effect of having the code on the left and outputs like graphical visualizations on the right